# Are questions regarding digital recordings of theatre productions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a recording of the performance of `Waiting for Godot` by Ian McKellen and Patrick Stewart [online at the National Art Library](http://catalogue.nal.vam.ac.uk/ipac20/ipac.jsp?session=1L5515X00O558.957&profile=nal&source=%7E!horizon&view=subscriptionsummary&uri=full=3100001%7E!824114%7E!4&ri=40&aspect=subtab114&menu=search&ipp=20&spp=20&staffonly=&term=Waiting%20For%20Godot%20%C2%A0%20&index=TW&uindex=&aspect=subtab114&menu=search&ri=40&limitbox_2=LO01%20=%20tm).

Is it on-topic to ask how to access that recording, if at all possible?

Comment: Are you asking a technical question, e.g. "how do I use software x"?

Comment: @Hamlet Well, now that you paraphrased it this way, I realised that I am. An honour to speak to Hamlet as well :) What SE site do you recommend to ask this question at, or is there none that fits?

Comment: @Narusan I don't think there's a website on Stack Exchange that fits this question, unfortunately. You might try poking around some of the historical reddit pages to see if someone knows there.

Comment: Or you could ask the question in our site's chat room.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thanks for the link. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to go with **no**.

This proposed question is asking how to use a piece of software that we have no affiliation with, and it's only relation to the subject matter is that it is used to access books. While the content of the program is on topic, the system used to view it isn't (otherwise we'd have questions about how to use Kindles and Nooks and Google Drive and all sorts of stuff). I'm not sure where you should take this question, but I'm relatively certain that it's not here. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

### No.

This kind of question is, to my knowledge, off topic on the vast majority (if not *everywhere*) on the Stack Exchange network.

In addition to what @Mithrandir mentioned, it seems like a lot of questions like that would fall under [customer service for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Yes, I do recognize that that's a different site's FAQ, but the reasons listed there still apply: we don't know the answer. That's a question for the company that's distributing it. To quote:

> ... there might be some intrepid soul who has sailed these waters before, and come out alive. They might even be able to offer some insight. There might even be the occasional employee wandering these hallowed halls. But here's the problem:
>
> We're not Google, Facebook or Apple Customer Service.
>
> We don't set policy for these companies. We don't have telephone lines, confirmation code generators, or any authority to make decisions on your behalf. We don't track changes to policy, except by anecdote and hearsay, so any answer we give you today is going to be wrong tomorrow, if it isn't already wrong.
>
> Here's the other problem:
>
> We're not here to act as customer support on any company's behalf.
>
> That's not our mission. We're here to help you with your challenges writing code [or, in our cases, challenges with interpreting and reading literature]. If that code involves some company's API, fine. We're more than happy to help you with that. But we don't know if your app will be approved. We can't give you a confirmation code. We don't know how long it will take for Microsoft to release that shiny new thing.
>
> We just don't know. All we can do is refer you to customer support.

For general software questions, there are always the Super User and Web Applications Stack Exchange sites, but please be sure to check their help centers before posting to make sure that your question fits within their rules.